# Problem with NSString

Tags: iphone

I have some strange problem,my code is

```
NSLog(@"A:%@",a);
b=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"1800-%@",a];
NSLog(@"B:%@",b);
```

The **output** is,

```
A:5555555
B:Safari free
```

I dont know what the problem is?

Comment: What are the types of `a` and `b`?

Comment: `NSString`, or `NSString *`? (I'm guessing the latter, since I don't know how it would compile, otherwise.)

Comment: NSString * only marcelo.  i assigned IBOutlet that the problem. @kingofbliss mentioned that i his answer. Anyway thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have once encountered this kind of problem. The mistake i did was, i assigned IBOutlet to NSString

```
IBOutlet NSString *string;
```

You may also assign IBOutlet to that NSString, please check, if so remove that.

Comment: OMG how i didnt notice this!! Thanks man. its my mistake while using ctrl+c, ctrl+v :). Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Could be memory overwrites/over releasing, try running with NSZombieEnabled set in the environment (edit the environment in Xcode executable settings) or enable GuardMalloc (in the run menu).

Instruments now has a zombie tool too.

Comment: thanks for your help. i have received solution from kingofbliss, now it solved. I think if it is releases means it will crash.